# When submitting form not calling controller function

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, forms

When clicking the submit button the auth function isn't being called, I haven't been able to figure out why.

html for the template for all pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app ="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>MyApp @ViewBag.Title</title>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/Login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("myApp", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - myApp</p>
    </footer>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

html for this pages view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2></h2>
<div id="loginBox">
  <auth-modal></auth-modal>
</div>
```

here is the html for the custom directive:

```
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-signin" name="authForm" ng-submit="auth()" ng-controller ="AuthController" novalidate>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="user name" ng-model ="AuthController.user.username" required autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model ="AuthController.user.password" required>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Here is the JS:

```
(function () {
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('AuthModalController', function () {
    MyApp.user = {};
    console.log("AuthModalController ran");
    $(".modal").modal({});
});

MyApp.directive("authModal", function () {
    return { restrict: 'E', templateUrl: '\\js\\templates\\auth-modal.html', controller: 'AuthModalController',controllerAs: 'authmodalCtrl'}
});

MyApp.controller('AuthController',function () {
    this.user = {};
    console.log("AuthController ran");
    this.auth = function () {
        console.log("user " + this.user);

    };
});
})();
```

MVC 5 Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class MyAppController : Controller
   {
       //
       // GET: /MyApp/
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
          return View();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need your controller code.

Comment: @CBauer its the last code block i posted

Comment: I'm looking at it, you have `MyApp.controller('AuthController',['$scope',function () {` and you need `MyApp.controller('AuthController',['$scope',function (**$scope**) {`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63672/discussion-between-c-bauer-and-timigen).

Comment: Try to switch from minified angular to the non-minified, the exception details will be clearer and we might be able to help you (but honestly we've strayed so far from the original post this should be a new question).

Comment: Also did you remember to still do `var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])`

Comment: just so you know, I ran through the examples on the angular.js site and found that they did not work unless I included the `ng-app="app-name-from-module"` directive on the controller object. So sorry to have wasted your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I'm adding on here that I couldn't get the code linked below to run except by adding the ng-app="app-name-from-module" directive alongside the controller declaration on the form object, which is not in the linked angular-js documentation!

Reading just the documentation I noticed quite a few issues,

1) <strike>You're declaring "myApp" and using "MyApp" unless thats an obfuscation error.</strike>

2) I think your controller is missing a few things per the documentation (esp $scope variable, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

2a) You're not attaching the auth function to the $scope

3) The .controller seems to take a string and an array as an argument, not a generic function.

Per: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

```
<script>
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.text = 'hello';
      $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.text) {
          $scope.list.push(this.text);
          $scope.text = '';
        }
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form ng-app="submitExample" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
</form>
```